# Result of power iteration applied to defective matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra

The power iteration algorithm for eigenvalues/eigenvectors is applied when there
is a dominant simple eigenvalue strictly larger than the rest.

But what of the defective case? In the simplest form, this is
$$A = \begin{pmatrix}
\lambda & 1 \\
0 & \lambda
\end{pmatrix}, \hspace{12pt} \lambda \neq 0$$

I can invoke Gelfand's spectral radius formula to conclude $\|A^n(x)\| \rightarrow \lambda^n$ for all $x$.

Is there a simpler way to see this without this machinery? Also, can we still conclude convergence or non convergence of a subsequence to an eigenvector?

Comment: What does $\|A^n(x)\| \rightarrow \lambda^n$ for all $x$ mean?

Answer (score 0):

Consider a matrix (size $n \times n$) of the form
$$
A = 
\pmatrix{
\lambda&1&\\
&\lambda&1\\
&&\ddots&\\
&&&\lambda
}
$$
We have
$$
A^k =
\pmatrix{
\lambda^k&k\lambda^{k-1}&\cdots&\frac{d^{n-1}}{d\lambda^{n-1}}[\lambda^k]\\
&\lambda^k&k\lambda^{k-1}&\cdots\\
&&\ddots&\\
&&&\lambda^k
} 
$$
I'm not sure how to use this to fully answer your question, but perhaps this will help.